# jQuery Mobile listview arrows not there/visible

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile

In my listview, I am positioning images using the `position: absolute` on the right side of certain list items. When a list item has too much text, I am wrapping it using `white-space: normal !important`.

The problem is that the text of the list items isn't wrapping soon enough as it doesn't take the position of the images into account due to their `absolute` positioning.

To counter this, I have wrapped the list item's `<a>` tag in a div with a width less than 100% however this causes the list item's right arrow to disappear.

Is there any way to fix this without adding a new arrow to each affected list item? Perhaps there is another way to cause the list item's text to wrap sooner?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/gfjhj0bg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just increase the right-padding of the `<a>` element within the listitem

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gfjhj0bg/3/)**

```
ul > li > a {
    padding-right: 100px !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```